# Strange error with php56-imagick

Tags: php, imagick

I've broken my mind with this problem! Please, help)

### Versions

**MacOS version (El Capitan)**

```
$ sw_vers -productVersion

10.11.1
```

**PHP version**

```
$ php -v

PHP 5.6.14 (cli) (built: Oct  3 2015 14:54:13) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.3.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2015, by Derick Rethans
```

**IMagick version**

```
$ php -i | grep imagick

imagick
imagick module => enabled
imagick module version => 3.1.2
imagick classes => Imagick, ImagickDraw, ImagickPixel, ImagickPixelIterator
imagick.locale_fix => 0 => 0
imagick.progress_monitor => 0 => 0
```

**ImageMagick version**

```
$ identify -version

Version: ImageMagick 6.9.2-4 Q16 x86_64 2015-10-11 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2015 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC Modules 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib freetype jng jpeg ltdl lzma png tiff xml zlib
```

### Problem

This simple php script with 3 lines **run.php**

```
<?php

$img = '/Users/vkulikov/Downloads/1444827520-120x60.gif';
$imagick = new \Imagick();
$imagick->readImage($img);
```

When i am trying to execute it in console i have this strange output

```
$ php run.php 

Assertion failed: (wand->signature == WandSignature), function MagickClearException, file wand/magick-wand.c, line 246.
Magick: abort due to signal 6 (SIGABRT) "Abort"...
Abort trap: 6
```

Have any ideas?

Comment: @Danack yes, sorry. But the question still actually